# Sync data from on prem SQL Server to Azure to be consumed in Azure Search Service

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am working on a POC that needs the data to be moved to Azure so that Azure Search Service always provide me the latest data.

Here is my situation:

- SQL Server deployed on-premises has a database that has few tables that always gets updated by user inputs. Tables are having millions of records and new records gets added/old data gets updated every day depending upon transactions
- Planning to leverage Azure Search Service capabilities to search the data in my website

What is the best way to achieve the functionality regarding data sync between an on-premises SQL Server database and Azure? Any good architecture direction would help me in my decision making.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to achieve the functionality regarding data sync between an on-premises SQL Server database and Azure?

I'd say the best option given the information you have provided is to use [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync).

You can setup a sync group and have Azure pull your data at regular intervals from your on-prem database to an Azure SQL database.